# hibernate + eclipse : mapping doesn't exist for table

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, orm

I have installed Hibernate Tools in my IDE Eclipse. When i launch the Hibernate Console Configuration, it seem to work well. I can show the diagram and the table and its tables. Nevertheless, when i try to make a request by using tomcat, i get an error : « mapping doesn’t exists for Author ».

You can find the detailed error and the code below :

class Author.java

```
package com.catalog.Catalog.Models;
// Generated 18 avr. 2018 19:38:32 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.8.Final

/**
 * Author generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Author implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7203876984282243151L;
    private int authorId;
    private String authorLastname;
    private String authorFirstname;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(int authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public Author(int authorId, String authorLastname, String 
    authorFirstname) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
        this.authorLastname = authorLastname;
        this.authorFirstname = authorFirstname;
    }

    public int getAuthorId() {
        return this.authorId;
    }

    public void setAuthorId(int authorId) {
        this.authorId = authorId;
    }

    public String getAuthorLastname() {
        return this.authorLastname;
    }

    public void setAuthorLastname(String authorLastname) {
        this.authorLastname = authorLastname;
    }

    public String getAuthorFirstname() {
        return this.authorFirstname;
    }

    public void setAuthorFirstname(String authorFirstname) {
        this.authorFirstname = authorFirstname;
    }

}
```

The struts action which is used in order to make the database operations:

```
package com.catalog.Catalog.actions;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import com.catalog.Catalog.Models.Author;
import com.catalog.Catalog.Utils.HibernateUtil;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8465571610682762828L;
    private List<Author> auteur;
    Session session = null;


    public List<Author> getAuteur() {
        return auteur;
    }



    public void setAuteur(List<Author> auteur) {
        this.auteur = auteur;
    }



    public String execute() {
        this.session = 
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query<Author> authorQuery = session.createQuery("from Author");
        auteur = authorQuery.list();
        return SUCCESS ;

    }
}
```

The HibernateUtil class

```
package com.catalog.Catalog.Utils;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

The hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="Catalog">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Catalog</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Author.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/BookBasket.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/BookCopy.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Book.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Bookshelf.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Catalog.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Category.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Editor.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Library.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="com/catalog/Catalog/Models/Member.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.reveng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="author"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="book"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="book_basket"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="book_copy"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="bookshelf"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="catalog"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="category"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="editor"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="library"/>
  <table-filter match-schema="public" match-name="member"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

The Author.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18 avr. 2018 19:38:33 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.8.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping package="com.catalog.Catalog.Models" schema="catalog">
 <class name="com.catalog.Catalog.Models.Author" schema="public" table="author">
  <id name="authorId" type="int">
   <column name="author_id"/>
   <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="authorLastname" type="string">
   <column length="60" name="author_lastname"/>
  </property>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="authorFirstname" type="string">
   <column length="60" name="author_firstname"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Author is not mapped [from Author]
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    com.catalog.Catalog.actions.TestAction.execute(TestAction.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:426)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:372)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:438)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:250)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:85)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:203)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
cause mère

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Author is not mapped [from Author]
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    com.catalog.Catalog.actions.TestAction.execute(TestAction.java:34)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:899)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1544)
    ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:90)
    ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1620)
    ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91)
    ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:470)
    ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:434)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$3.execute(OgnlUtil.java:374)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecuteMethod(OgnlUtil.java:426)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.callMethod(OgnlUtil.java:372)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:438)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:293)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:250)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:179)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:49)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.doIntercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:137)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:201)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:67)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:85)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:101)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:160)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:175)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:99)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:167)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:203)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:196)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:48)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:574)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:79)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:141)
```

Thank you for your help

Vinz

Comment: try to use <mapping class=""/>

Comment: Do i have to change the hibernate.hbm.xml file or create in AJP ?

Comment: yes, need to replace as `<mapping class=""/>`

Comment: i did it but i always have the problem.

Comment: Try change name of Autror entity class, for example AutrorEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this way for retrieving the session factory:

```
final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure().build();
            session = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```